# spark dataframe pivoting is throwing AssertionError: assertion failed: unsafe symbol Unstable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax

I have a dataframe i.e. resultDf as below

```
+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|model_family_id|classification_type|classification_value|benchmark_type_code|          data_date|data_item_code|data_item_value_numeric|data_item_value_string|
+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|               MEAN|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                     15|                     b|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|            OBS_CNT|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                      4|                     b|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|         OBS_CNT_CA|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                      4|                  null|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|       PERCENTILE_0|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                     15|                     b|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|      PERCENTILE_10|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                     15|                     b|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|     PERCENTILE_100|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                     15|                     b|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|      PERCENTILE_25|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                     15|                     b|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|      PERCENTILE_50|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                     15|                     b|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|      PERCENTILE_75|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                     15|                     b|
|              1|            COUNTRY|                 AGO|      PERCENTILE_90|2018-03-31 00:00:00|   CREDITSCORE|                     15|                     b|
+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

I pivot a table based on "benchmark_type_code" column ,
need to implement below business logic

If(data_item_code) is   "SCORE"  OR "PG_SCORE"
           ====>  pick data_item_value_string  as the value 
else 
==>  pick data_item_value_numeric as the value

For that I have written below code

```
   val pivot_resultDf =  resultDf.groupBy("model_family_id","classification_type","classification_value" ,"benchmark_type_code","data_date")
                .pivot("benchmark_type_code")
                .agg( first( 
                        when( col("data_item_code").===("SCORE"),  col("data_item_value_numeric"))
                             .otherwise(col("data_item_value_string"))
                    ) )
```

But I am getting error in agg function @ when condition

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: unsafe symbol Unstable (child of <none>) in runtime reflection universe
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:205)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TypeSymbol.<init>(Symbols.scala:3030)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.newStubSymbol(Symbols.scala:521)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readExtSymbol$1(UnPickler.scala:258)
    at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.readSymbol(UnPickler.scala:286)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.unpickleClass(JavaMirrors.scala:619)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:28)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter$$anonfun$complete$1.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.slowButSafeEnteringPhaseNotLaterThan(SymbolTable.scala:263)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.SymbolLoaders$TopClassCompleter.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:25)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1535)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.$eq$eq$eq(Column.scala:262)
```

What am I doing wrong here ? how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working

.agg(  first(
                  when(  col("data").isin("x","a","y","z")  ,
                   when(  col("code").isin("aa","bb")  ,  col("numeric")).otherwise(col("string"))
                          )
                 .otherwise(col("numeric"))
                )

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are getting an assertion error, But i am able to get the results successfully. Usually assertion errors are syntactic errors. Please check the line endings and try to execute on spark shell to see where the real gap is. 
 Find the screenshot which shows that i am able to get desired result.

[image]

Comment: I have few columns like A, B , C, D, E .
I am groupBy("A","B").pivot("C).agg(first(...)) ..... But the resultant dataframe does not have origianl D & D column data right ? How can get those too in my resultant dataframe ?

Comment: can you please help this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591966/how-to-get-non-groupby-column-of-pivoting-in-spark-sql

Comment: instead of "benchmark_type_code" column its values should be in the pivoted columns right ? I am not getting those in other when condition, what should i do ?